# How can I load in constants from a python file to a bash script?

Tags: python, bash

I have a python file where a bunch of constant values are maintained,

```
constant_value = 5
constant_address = '127.0.0.1'
constant_file_path = '/home/user/work'
```

I am working on a bash script that will use these constants, but I do not want to go the route of using a config file to keep these values in or something that they both could grab from, I want to keep these constants maintained in the python file.

How could I read these constants into my bash script to use?

I am finding some similar ideas online but I am a bit confused as to whether there would be any issues with some of the constants being int for example, and others being strings, etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Effectively you'd have to write a Python parser in bash. I'd strongly recommend rethinking that as a plan.

Comment: did you try to source it? in bash: source myconstants.py (you've to delete spaces around the = sign)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply remove the spaces - and you have a "polyglot" file that's valid in both Python and BASH:

```
constant_value=5
constant_address='127.0.0.1'
constant_file_path='/home/user/work'
```

Then in BASH:

```sh
bash-3.2$ source config.py
bash-3.2$ echo $constant_file_path
/home/user/work
bash-3.2$ python3 -c "import config; print(config.constant_file_path)"
/home/user/work
```

Comment: THANK YOU, I had no idea it could be this simple, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can read Python values with Bash without modifying the Python script (and without sourcing it which can be potentially problematic).

Let's say you have `script.py` as following -

```
SOME_VARIABLE = "some_value"
```

Then running `VAR=$(python3 -c 'from script import SOME_VARIABLE; print(SOME_VARIABLE)')` gives you the value of Python `SOME_VARIABLE` variable into Bash `VAR` variable.